# Sorted list by using the first element

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I have list.

```
li = ['455:1', '2919:1', '275:71', '2840:64']
```

I tried:

```
print sorted(li)
result: ['275:71', '2840:64', '2919:1', '455:1']
```

and

```
print sorted(li, key=itemgetter(0))
result: ['2919:1', '275:71', '2840:64', '455:1']
```

and

```
print sorted(li, key=lambda x: (x[0]))
result: ['2919:1', '275:71', '2840:64', '455:1']
```

I want to get

```
['275:71', '455:1', '2840:64', '2919:1']
```

Any suggestion to fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your strings and turn the first value into an integer:

```
sorted(li, key=lambda s: int(s.split(':')[0]))
```

otherwise you'll just sort lexicographically instead of numerically.

Demo:

```
>>> li = ['455:1', '2919:1', '275:71', '2840:64']
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda s: int(s.split(':')[0]))
['275:71', '455:1', '2840:64', '2919:1']
```

`itemgetter(0)` and `x[0]` only select the first character of the string, so sorting on `'2'` versus `'4'` *only*, leaving the ordering between values with the same initial character untouched.